# PostCast Server - UTF-8 encoding. It is possible?

Tags: php, email, post, smtp, sendmail

Welcome. I have a simple question about PostCast Server. It is possible to set UTF-8 encoding in this ?? If it is possible then where and how I can do this ?? I will be very glad, if I get any helpful informations.